# How to change data in XML file?Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab

Hi i know there have been asked many questions regarding changing content of XML in Matlab. But i tried different answers to this question(present on SO) but they did not work in my case. Here is my XML file structure

```
<annotation>
    <folder>n02749479</folder>
    <filename>n02749479_54</filename>
    <source>
        <database>ImageNet database</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>500</width>
        <height>277</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>n02749479</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>118</xmin>
            <ymin>69</ymin>
            <xmax>473</xmax>
            <ymax>193</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I want to change the tags in `<bndbox>` tag. I want to change values of`xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax`. I am able to get the values of these tags but i am unable to set values of these tags.
**Question:**
How to change content of tags mentioned above?

Comment: It might help you https://www.thewizz.art/2022/01/06/how-to-modify-an-xml-attribute-value-using-matlab/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab supporst java interface to xml. For example to change `xmin` in `bndbox` you could do:

```
xmlfile = fullfile('/tmp/test.xml');

DOMnode = xmlread(xmlfile);
bndbox_elem = DOMnode.getElementsByTagName('bndbox');
xmin_elem = bndbox_elem.item(0).getElementsByTagName('xmin');
xmin_elem.item(0).setTextContent('3233')

xmlwrite('/tmp/test2.xml',DOMnode);
```